# using whois with torify and detailed info

Tags: anonymity, debian

I tried `tor-prompt` and while the minimalist /help gives some info. it doesn't tell if I can run the `whois` command through it or some other command utility which gives me the info. I tried the following on the prompt and was met by -

```
>>> whois 1337x.to
  File "<console>", line 1
    whois 1337x.to
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I run simply whois on the same website I get Timeouts most of the time or some barely info. the website has been banned/censored in the country.

I am on Debian stretch/testing with few bits of sid/unstable.

Update - Even tried simple torify with the same result, of course my understanding may be total lacking about the process -

```
[$] torify whois 1337x.to                                                                                                           
Timeout.
```

On the other hand curl and other such apps. work fine with torify. I had used https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify way back to make changes to tor so I could also use CLI services using tor and anonymity.

Update 04/10/2017 - Is there a way to tell non-profits for whom anonymity might be important but do not know what setting needs to be changed either in apache or whatever webserver they use to let anonymous people also get their details. I do see lot of vulnerable people who could use such info. for good.

Comment: `tor-prompt` is for managing and interacting with Tor, not for using applications with Tor. `torify whois` should work. It's likely related to the specific whois server used by the `.to` ccTLD either not having much information or blocking connections from Tor.

Comment: aha, interesting, didn't know that. I did look at few other sites, non-profit ones and few of them were able to release their info. but others didn't .